# Does the order matter when declaring classes in Java?

Tags: java

Why this code does not even compile?

```
public class T {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class A extends B {}
        class B {}
        B a = new A();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Error:(10, 25) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class B
  location: class com.test.T
Error:(12, 15) java: incompatible types
  required: B
  found:    A
```

Does the order really matter when declaring such classes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it matters *for local classes*. It's worth noting that local classes are *incredibly* rare in real code. I can only remember *ever* using one once. However, for the sake of interest...

From the JLS, [section 6.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3):

> The scope of a local class declaration immediately enclosed by a block (§14.2) is the rest of the immediately enclosing block, including its own class declaration.

Now "rest" isn't terribly clear, but I believe it means "from this point onwards". So basically `B` isn't in scope in the declaration of `A`, hence the error.

For added fun, before the declaration of `B` you can refer to a *different* type called `B`:

```
public class T {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class A extends B {}
        class B {}
        B a = new A();
    }
}

class B {}
```

Gives:

> error: incompatible types: A cannot be converted to B

Comment: Now that it is 2023 local _records_ are very useful, and it is sad that they can't refer to each other.

Answer (score 2):

For top-level classes, no.

For local classes, yes, but see John Skeet's answer for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32254520/257090

Java, like C#, and most other modern compilers, parse the whole file first, as well as other files or imports in the same scope, to populate the compiler symbol table with the top-level type symbols that it sees (without further resolving the internals of those types at this step), and then in a later step, the compiler resolves symbol references; once all symbols have been gathered, they have no lexical ordering or priority, as if they were all declared on the same line, simultaneously. This is how it implements the following concepts (from JLS - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3)

> A declaration is said to be in scope at a particular point in a
>   program if and only if the declaration's scope includes that point.
>
> The scope of the declaration of an observable (§7.4.3) top level
>   package is all observable compilation units (§7.3).
>
> The scope of a top level type (§7.6) is all type declarations in the
>   package in which the top level type is declared.

among others...

This is why it is simple to create cyclical relationships in Java/C# without the forward declarations required in older languages like C/C++ where the compiler only looks "backwards", so a forward declaration is a dummy or placeholder for something that is really forward.

However, inside the Java method body, Java uses a lexical order and treats classes with the same ordering rules as local variables. (See John Skeet's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32254520/257090)

I can think of a couple of reasons why this has to be so for sanity, but it comes down to decisions made by the compiler / language designers. My opinion is that it is simply for consistency. Otherwise, we'd have 2 different rules for local things and that sort of thing would get confusing. If you've ever done a lot of Perl programming, you know how challenging it can be to maintain a mental cache of special cases and context specific rules.

Answer (score -2):

Change this :

public class T {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    B b = new A();
}
```

}

class B {
}

class A extends B {
}

Comment: Yes, I tried this. But the question was about class order in the scope of method.

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation would help current and future readers to understand it even better.